# Possibility of React Native for an Android app?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, smartphone

It a really numb question and i hope i am on the good forum to ask it, but you are the only that can answer it (i am self learning codding and nobody that i know can answer this question).

I would like to know it is possible to use React Native to build an smartphone application that for exemple will have access to the latest sms received.

To be more precise i would like to know if is possible to build using react native an application that get trigerred when a sms is received and that forward it to an email address.

Thank you for your help, i know it sound like a very numb question but nobody else that i know can answer it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get access to SMS via `android.permission.READ_SMS`, so from technical standpoint you should have no problem with that. You will need a user approve on permissions though.

Comment: Thank for your answer and for helping a self learner noob that all i needed to know :-)